# Рассчитать количество байт в данной строке кода?

Tags: ассемблер

Даная строчка кода:

`not byte ptr B2[eax+edx]`

Я рассчитала так:

```
not - 1 байт
byte ptr - 1 байт
B2[eax+edx] - 4 байта
modR/M - 1 байт
```

Но преподаватель сказал что неправильно, где ошибка?

Comment: Размер инструкции зависит от режима работы процессора, для которого она скомпилирована. без его указания посчитать невозможно. Там могут быть например префиксы смены размерности операнда или адреса, которых иногда не хватает и может появляться SIB-байт

Comment: 32-битный режим - 7 байт, 16-битный - 8 байт, 64-битный - 8 байт. По поводу интерпретации байт нужно смотреть, может оказаться, что опкод определяет не именно not, а группу команд, а конкретная команда определяется по второму триплету mod r/m.